# How to realize the Auto answer function in android4.0 of mobile phone?

Tags: android

I want to set a function that it can receive the call automatically above the android 4.0 versions.
The code like this：

```
synchronized void autoAnswerCall(){

  Context context = TApplication.nowApplication;

   try

         {

          //insert earphones

             Intent localIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);

             localIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

             localIntent1.putExtra("state", 1);

             localIntent1.putExtra("microphone", 1);

             localIntent1.putExtra("name", "Headset");

             context.sendOrderedBroadcast(localIntent1, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");


             //Press the headset button

             Intent localIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);

             KeyEvent localKeyEvent1 = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);

             localIntent2.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", localKeyEvent1);

             context.sendOrderedBroadcast(localIntent2, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");


             //Open the headset button

             Intent localIntent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);

             KeyEvent localKeyEvent2 = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK);

             localIntent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", localKeyEvent2);

             context.sendOrderedBroadcast(localIntent3, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");


             //Pull out earphones

             Intent localIntent4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);

             localIntent4.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

             localIntent4.putExtra("state", 0);

             localIntent4.putExtra("microphone", 1);

             localIntent4.putExtra("name", "Headset");

             context.sendOrderedBroadcast(localIntent4, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

         }catch (Exception e){

             e.printStackTrace();

         }

}
```

It realized the Auto answer function in android2.3 of simulator and mobile phone. It also can in android4.0 simulator. But in android4.0 mobile phone it can not.

I use aidl reflex, it can not. How to realize the Auto answer function in android4.0 of mobile phone?
Any idea？

Answer (score 0):

You can use Telephony manager to receive your ringing call,For this you have to put this code in Broadcast receiver

```
 if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {          
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
            Class c = null;
                 c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                 Method m = null;
                 m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                 m.setAccessible(true);              
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                telephonyService.answerRingingCall();

       }
```

Comment: Did you gave these permissions in manifest....<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />

Comment: @ Ganesh Kumar YA. I have add this permission. but it is still have the error. I do not know how to solve this problem.